# Connect to wamp server

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin, wamp

I keep getting an error message:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\Website\index.php on line 46

Below is my code. What could be going wrong? I am just using the stock root account for now.

```
<?php

$dbserver="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$connection=mysql_connect("$dbserver","$username","$password")or die("could not connect to the server");

//execute an SQL statement and return a recordset
$rs = $connection->execute("SELECT product_name FROM products");
$num_columns = $rs->Fields->Count();

echo "<table border='1'>"; 
echo "<tr><th>Name</th></tr>";
while (!$rs->EOF) //looping through the recordset (until End Of File)
{
     echo "<tr>";
     for ($i=0; $i <  $num_columns; $i++) {
         echo "<td><a href=\"product.php?id=" . $rs->Fields('id').value . "\">" . $rs->Fields($i)->value . "</a></td>";
     }
     echo "</tr>";
     $rs->MoveNext();
}
echo "</table>";

//close the recordset and the database connection
$rs->close();
$rs = null;
$conn->close();
$conn = null;
?>
```

Comment: Where is line 46? Is this index.php?

Answer (score 0):

The function `mysql_connect` returns a resource. This means the variable `$connection` is not an object and so you cannot call the function `execute` on it. This explains the error message.

Most of the database-related function calls in the code (`Fields`, `MoveNext`, ...) seem to be [ADOdb](http://adodb.sourceforge.net/)-related. These will not work on a resource (or rowset) created by the `mysql_*` functions.

See the documentation for ADOdb and the documentation for the mysql extension for PHP for more information.

Since the original mysql extension for PHP is deprecated and ADOdb is not updated very frequently, I would suggest using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for your database access.